# How to set state in parent component and access it in child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components, react-props

I have an object array (videoData) that is getting rendered inside parent component (Videocard) with the help of map function, which is also rendering a delete button along with each item.

I want to set the "dltId" variable to current item id when delete button is clicked with the help of the function name handleDeleteNoteFunc() and then pass the "dltId" to child component (DeleteModal).

In parent component iam mapping the videoData array and i want to access the corresponding item id inside child component (DeleteModal), Iam setting the current item id to dltId and then passing dltId to child as a prop, but when iam logging dltId in child inside the function handlClickFunc(), its showing UNDEFINED, how to set and access "dltId" in child component (DeleteModal)?

The child component (DeleteModal) is a form what is conditionally getting rendered.

Parent component :-

```
const Videocard = ({ videoData }) => {
  const [dltId, setdltId] = useState()
  let dispModal = true

  function handleDeleteNoteFunc(videoId) {
    setdltId(videoId)
  }
  return (
    <>
      {videoData.map((item) => {
        return (
          <button
            className="notesBox"
            onClick={() => handleDeleteNoteFunc(item.id)}
          >
            Delete
          </button>
        )
      })}
      {dispModal && <DeleteModal dltId={dltId} />}
    </>
  )
}
```

Child Component :-

```
const DeleteModal = ({ dltId }) => {
  function handlClickFunc(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(dltId);     // UNDEFINED
  }
  return (
    <button
      type="submit"
      value="Submit"
      onClick={(e) => handlClickFunc(e)}
    >
      Delete Note as well !
    </button>
  )
}
```

Comment: If you click on one of your delete button then it will not show undefined.
Maybe you want to show your `DeleteModal` only when you clicked first on a delete button?

Comment: i want to show DeleteModal whenever user will click the delete button along with each item , and the id of that particular item should be passed to DeleteModal

Comment: Then you don't need the `dispModal` you can only use the `dltId` like : `{!!dltId && <DeleteModal dltId={dltId} />}`

Comment: it is working fine, but the only issue is the form (DeleteModal) is only getting opened up when iam clicking delete button twice, how to fix that?

Comment: Can you show the id of the item?

Comment: id of the item ? i dint get it, its a 6 digit unique number

Comment: Strange, as you can see here : https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-sun-mf5ec8?file=/src/App.js
It is working. Maybe add the null in your `useState`

Comment: null is not working, i think since DeleteModal is a form , iam still dependent on dispModal to turn false to close the form , but iam depenedent on dltId  to open the form , i guess that is causing a conflict

Comment: Maybe update your post with your actual code. Not easy to help if we don't have everything